# MatterJs local simulation is in diffrent speed then in the cloud

Tags: javascript, matter.js

```
  Matter.Events.on(runner, 'beforeUpdate', (e) => {
          Matter.Body.setVelocity(body, {
            x: -2,
            y: body.velocity.y,
          })
  })
```

Im setting the velocity like this.
my problem is depending where i run this code it object moves in diffrent speed.

if i run it with node 16.4.0 on my local machine it moves the object super slow.

event log from my machine

```
{
  timestamp: 949.9999999999992,
  name: 'beforeUpdate',
  source: {
    fps: 38.873999999999995,
    correction: 1,
    deltaSampleSize: 60,
    counterTimestamp: 1647108816311,
    frameCounter: 19,
    deltaHistory: [],
    timePrev: null,
    timeScalePrev: 1,
    frameRequestId: undefined,
    isFixed: true,
    enabled: true,
    delta: 16.666666666666668,
    deltaMin: 16.666666666666668,
    deltaMax: 33.333333333333336,
    events: { beforeTick: [Array], beforeUpdate: [Array] }
  }
}
```

if i run this code as example on a heroku machine wiht node 16.4.0 it has the speed which was intended.

event log on heroku

```
{
   timestamp: 733.333333333333,
   name: 'beforeUpdate',
   source: {
     fps: 1647108632.865,
     correction: 1,
     deltaSampleSize: 60,
     counterTimestamp: 1647108632865,
     frameCounter: 44,
     deltaHistory: [],
     timePrev: null,
     timeScalePrev: 1,
     frameRequestId: undefined,
     isFixed: true,
     enabled: true,
     delta: 16.666666666666668,
     deltaMin: 16.666666666666668,
     deltaMax: 33.333333333333336,
     events: { beforeTick: [Array], beforeUpdate: [Array] }
   }
}
```

is also tried with or without fixed update

```
  const runner = Matter.Runner.create({
    isFixed: true,
  })
```

what do i need to set that the move always at the same speed?

Answer (score 0):

When creating your runner, set `isFixed: true`

```js
const r = Runner.create({ isFixed: true });
```

Check out what it does here:

```js
export interface IRunnerOptions {
    /**
     * A `Boolean` that specifies if the runner should use a fixed timestep (otherwise it is variable).
     * If timing is fixed, then the apparent simulation speed will change depending on the frame rate (but behaviour will be deterministic).
     * If the timing is variable, then the apparent simulation speed will be constant (approximately, but at the cost of determininism).
     *
     * @default false
     */
    isFixed?: boolean | undefined;

    // other stuff
    // ...
}
```